# Can't build consent-library:1.0.7

Tags: android, gradle, sdk

I can't build my Project when I add I follow [https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent]
I got below error!

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could
>   not resolve com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.7.

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
   // maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
 }

 allprojects {
    repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
     maven {
         url "https://maven.google.com"
     }
    }
  }



   dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.7'
```

}

Answer (score 2):

there only is a version `1.0.6`, as the link you've provided states:

```
implementation "com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.6"
```

for it to work, you'd also need to add this plugin to the `buildscript` dependencies:

```
classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0"
```

and apply that plugin at the bottom of the file:

```
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

and a `google-services.json` file needs to be added to the project, which provides the `ga_trackingId`... see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin).

Comment: i try it also but still not working..@Martin Zeitler

Comment: @huilo but it should; try to clean/make the project once. the `google()` repository is there and it should ordinary fetch the `1.0.6`. if there is any version conflict, just add the error message above.